# Yii2 - Como incluir varios registros usando activeform e checkbox

Tags: php, yii

Olá, estou usando o Yii pra testar algumas coisas, eu tenho uma tabela chamado Pedido e outra tabela chamado ProdutosPedido e nesta tabela tem o id_pedido e id_produto, eu queria no mesmo formulario incluir varios registros nesta tabela ( ProdutosPedido) com o mesmo valor do id_pedido mudando apenas o id_produto, tetei fazer isso usando um checkbox no formulário mas da um erro

View do formulario de adição de produtos ao pedido:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' =>['produtos-pedidos/create'], 'id' => 'adiciona-produtos', 'method' => 'post',]); ?>

<?= $form->field($modelProdutoPedido, 'id_produto')->checkboxList(ArrayHelper::map($modelProduto -> find()->all(), 'id', 'nome')) ?>
<?= $form-> field($modelProdutoPedido, 'id_pedido') -> hiddenInput(['value' => $pedidoId]) -> label('false') ?>
<div class="form-group">

    <?= Html::submitButton($modelProdutoPedido->isNewRecord ? 'Adicionar + produtos' : 'Update', ['class' => $modelProdutoPedido->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success btn-adiciona-produtos' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Controller do ProdutosPedidos@Create :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new ProdutosPedidos();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['//pedidos/view', 'id' => $model->id_pedido]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Se eu fizer desta forma recebo um erro ( Array to string conversion ) oque deve ser devido a estar passando varioas valores no campo "id_produto" , tentei fazer um loop pra ir salvando um por um porém não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi, estava com problemas para pegar oque o formulário enviava pram mim, oque acabou sendo um array dentro de um array (...)

O Front esta inalterado, só precisei de mudar no controller, segue o codigo novo

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new ProdutosPedidos();



    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){

        $idsProdutos = Yii::$app -> request -> post("ProdutosPedidos",['id_produto']);

        foreach ($idsProdutos['id_produto'] as $produto) {
            $model->id_produto = $produto ;
            $model->isNewRecord = true;
            $model->save();
        }
        return $this->redirect(['//pedidos/view', 'id' => $model->id_pedido]);
    }

}
```

Nesse código eu só altero no modelo que eu recebo do formulario o id referente ao produto e mantenho o resto ( id do pedido) intacto .

Ta funcionando, mas se alguém souber uma maneira mais simples/eficiente eu agradeço.